# Change button(textbox etc..) backcolor and forecolor with rgb slider from another form

Tags: vb.net

So yeah i did a form with a RGB slider wich generates a color, and i that when i close this form my r,g,b variables (integers) be sent to my other to be used to change the selected button's color here's what i got so far... (some of the code is in french rouge =red , vert = green and bleu=blue as for lbl stands for label and tb for trackbar)

```
Public Property r As Integer
Public Property g As Integer
Public Property b As Integer

Private Sub tbrouge_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbrouge.Scroll
    lblrouge.Text = tbrouge.Value
    prgb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(tbrouge.Value, tbvert.Value, tbbleu.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub tbvert_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbvert.Scroll
    lblvert.Text = tbvert.Value
    prgb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(tbrouge.Value, tbvert.Value, tbbleu.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub tbbleu_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbbleu.Scroll
    lblbleu.Text = tbbleu.Value
    prgb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(tbrouge.Value, tbvert.Value, tbbleu.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub btn_ok_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_ok.Click
    r = tbrouge.Value
    g = tbvert.Value
    b = tbbleu.Value
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom event.

```
Public Class frmColorChange
 Public Property r As Integer
 Public Property g As Integer
 Public Property b As Integer
 Public Event ColorChanged(r As Double, g As Double, b As Double)
Private Sub tbrouge_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbrouge.Scroll
 lblrouge.Text = tbrouge.Value
 prgb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(tbrouge.Value, tbvert.Value, tbbleu.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub tbvert_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbvert.Scroll
 lblvert.Text = tbvert.Value
 prgb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(tbrouge.Value, tbvert.Value, tbbleu.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub tbbleu_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbbleu.Scroll
 lblbleu.Text = tbbleu.Value
 prgb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(tbrouge.Value, tbvert.Value, tbbleu.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub btn_ok_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_ok.Click
 r = tbrouge.Value
 g = tbvert.Value
 b = tbbleu.Value
 'raise the event
 RaiseEvent ColorChanged(r, g, b)
 Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Usage:

```
'on the calling form
Dim frm As New frmColorChanged
Addhandler frm.ColorChanged, AddressOf ColorChanged
frm.ShowDialog()


'event handler
Private Sub ColorChanged(r As Double, g As Double, b As Double)
  'use the variables to set the new color
End Sub
```